# PHP code return no product based on filter

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to learn PHP code and I'm working on a tutorial I've found on androidhive (at [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) link).

I'm getting stuck when I request products data with a filter.
This is what androidhive does in code:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));
```

and in PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET["pid"])) {
    $pid = $_GET['pid'];

    // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products WHERE pid = $pid");

    if (!empty($result)) {
    // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $product = array();
            $product["pid"] = $result["pid"];
            $product["username"] = $result["username"];
            ...
            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["product"] = array();

            array_push($response["product"], $product);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found 1";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
    // no product found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No product found 2";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

While I'm basically doing this:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();                        
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "a"));
```

And in PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET["username"])) {
$username = $_GET['username'];

// get a product from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products WHERE username = $username");
```

So I'm only filtering products by a different value.

This however return me "No product found 2" so my result is empty i guess.
When I run the original code it works perfectly.

Anyone could help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the username type is varchar you have to modify you query in the following way

```
if (isset($_GET["username"])) {
   $username = $_GET['username'];
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products WHERE username = '$username'");

   /// other code
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Marking as accepted because you looked the source I guess. Do I need to put quotes even on string value?

Comment: yes, you have to put quotes for string,text and varchar type data.

Answer (score 1):

If username in your database is a string, you need quotes around $username.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products WHERE username = '$username'");
```